# howto filter Visual Studio Debug Output

Tags: visual-studio-2008, trace

I have a bunch of warnings (over 10000) in my debug output which can be savely ignored:
Warning: CFile::GetStatus() returns m_attribute without high-order flags

Is it possible to write a filter for this window?

Comment: This is a runtime message. All the answers apply to compile time warnings.
Does the ATL/MFC Trace Tool from the Tools menu help?

Comment: You are right, ATL/MFC Trace Tool can turn off this message.

Comment: I saved this settings. Do you know of a method to start this tool and load the settings automatically, when starting debugging?

Comment: AtlTraceLoadSettings(NULL); does it

Comment: I wish anyone could answer this fully.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2005, you can filter specific warning codes for your project outside of your code. Bring up the project's properties dialog and go to Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced. You should see a "Disable Specific Warnings" setting. Click on that and add the warning codes you want to filter. If the warning is C4996, for example, just enter 4996 without the C.

However, I don't think this method will work with warnings that have no code associated with them.

Newer versions of Visual Studio likely provide something along the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

[Disable it in the code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : nnnn )
#include "nasty.h"
#pragma warning( pop )
```

where `nnnn` is the warning's number (or a comma-separated list of such numbers).